# Disregard files in Excluded directories for Intellij/Pycharm searches

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Why are results from the [orange colored] `Excluded` directories showing up in `Find in Path` search results?

[image]

These are directories managed by `ionic` and should not be included.  How can these be removed from search results?

Note: there is a question from 2015 directly on this topic:  [Ignore a folder in search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014063/ignore-a-folder-in-search-results) .  But that question says to do exactly what I have already done - mark the folder as `Excluded`.  This issue uses the approach of several of the answers - and thus should supposedly work.

I am using `Pycharm Ultimate 2020.2` and `Intellij Ultimate 2020.2`.

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the reproducible test case. Excluded folders should not appear in Find in Path and I can't reproduce the issue in my project. It could be that you have some JS library set up for the files in the excluded directory.

Comment: thx @CrazyCoder!  I will do this in several days to a week: in middle of fire fight